# Not all products are showing up

Tags: products

So I just finished uploading my product feed in the Magento admin side. The feed went through just fine. The only issue now is that not all my products are showing.

I uploaded 834 products and only 12 are showing up. It's as if it is not showing the different pages to flip through to show the rest of the products. The first thing that comes to mind is the theme but everything seems fine to me there. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31293/i-enabled-a-product-but-this-product-is-not-showing-in-front-end/31310#31310

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

1 ) Ensure all products are set to enabled

2 ) Check that the products are set to In Stock or that they have manage stock set to "no"

3 ) Ensure products are set to visibility of "Catalog, Search"

4 ) Check that products are assigned to active categories

5 ) If on a multi store setup ensure that products are available on the store view you are reviewing

6 ) Go to System>Index Management select all re-index (you could reindex individually but reindexing it all won't hurt)

7 ) If you are running a 3rd party cache flush these as well. (note: most full page caches will not cache catalog/product pages)

Answer (score 0):

Please check all the products are associated with a website in the Admin and after that reindex everything.
Also, if you are in a category page, associate the products to the category or they wont show.
Most of the cases should be solved by that.