# I enabled a product, but this product is not showing in front end

Tags: product, status

I enabled a product, but this product is not showing in front end. I export product's csv, the status of this product value is 2(disable).
**I guess this is database error.**

Comment: How did you enable the product? Make sure you rebuilt your indexes.

Answer (score 2):

There can be numerous reasons why a Magento product is not shown. There is even an [extension](https://github.com/quafzi/Magento-Productvisibility) which shows you what could be wrong. Possible reasons are (taken from the extension page):

- product is not enabled
- product is not visible in catalog
- product has no website assigned
- product has no category assigned
- product is not set to "in stock"
- price index is not up to date
- stock index is not up to date